# Flume - loading files from file server to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, flume

I want to frequently load files from a file server to HDFS. Smaller files (2 MB to 20 MB) get loaded to the file server frequently. These files have to be loaded into the HDFS for MR process.
I see 2 problems before these files are made available for Map-Reduce jobs.

> 1. If these files are picked and loaded into HDFS at the time of running the MR job, then it takes long to load these into HDFS itself.
> 2. These smaller files have to be merged for MR job.

Questions

> 1. Can Flume be used to read these smaller files in the file server more frequently and stored in the HDFS?
> 2. I understand that there are CombineFileInputFormat and SequenceFiles to combine these files for processing, but Can these
>      smaller files be concatenated even before its stored in HDFS?

Answer (score 1):

Probable answers to question.

It's been a while since, I used flume. Still hope they help.

> 1. Can Flume be used to read these smaller files in the file server more frequently and stored in the HDFS?

Since data sources are customizable, Flume can be used to transport massive quantities of event data including but not limited to network traffic data, social-media-generated data, email messages and pretty much any data source possible.

Note: Flume does not support `tail` as a source. One can wrap the `tail` command in an exec source to stream the file.

For tailing files you can [check this out](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#exec-source)

An implementation of a Directory as a source for several files can be [tracked here](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/FLUME-26)

You can read about [HDFS sink here](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink), which can write to HDFS

> **2**.  I understand that there are CombineFileInputFormat and SequenceFiles
>   to combine these files for processing, but Can these smaller files be
>   concatenated even before its stored in HDFS?

Flume basically works on Event mechanism. The files can be rolled (close current file and create a new one) periodically based on the elapsed time or size of data or number of events. Check the same link for HDFS sink.

If number of files are large, you can probably use CombineFileINputFormat. I have no idea about how you can do that before writing to HDFS.

**Note:**

As I already said flume works on event based mechanism and as far as I know it's not for transferring files. If you look at this [interface for Event](http://flume.apache.org/releases/content/1.2.0/apidocs/org/apache/flume/Event.html), you'll notice the following methods

`byte[] getBody()`: Returns the raw byte array of the data contained in this event.

`void setBody(byte[] body)`: Sets the raw byte array of the data contained in this event.

So, the maximum size of an event is what byte[] can take. I don't know if your file can be put in that. You have to test it yourself. Furthermore, there are other conditions involved, which I don't recall now, that might hamper you from transferring files to HDFS.

Comment: Thanks JtheRocker. In fact, i don't have any control on the file server directory and tail is not required within the file. I need flume to transfer files in a network location to HDFS as and when it arrives or at an interval. The files may come at the rate of 1000 files per hour on average and 3000 files at peak.

Comment: Thanks. Are there other ways of ingesting data into HDFS, if not flume? One option is to load the files into the hadoop namenode's local file system and then use HDFS put command to load into HDFS.

Comment: @ManikandanKannan: You don't need to copy over files to namenode's local file system. What you can do is have any machine over your LAN become a Hadoop client. This can be even the machine from where you planning to transferring files to HDFS.